# Single report with parallel job execution on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins

Currently i have a job which executes 100+ test cases on 1 Jenkins slave and it runs for approximately 10 hours, How to split the test cases and run on multiple slaves and get 1 single report?